# determine file type of a file without extension

Tags: python, vim, file-type, pygments

I want to use `pygmentize` to highlight some script files (python/bash/...) without extension. But `pygmentize` requires me to specify the lexer using `-l`. It does not automatically identify the file type from the content.

I have the following options at hand, but none of them work now:

1. use `file -b --mime-type`. But this command output `x-python` and `x-shellscript` instead of `python` and `bash` and I don't know the rules
2. use `vim -e -c 'echo &ft|q' the_file`. For any file with or without file extension, vim has a mechanism to guess the file type. But it doesn't work. Since the output goes to the vim window and disappears after `q`.

What can I do?

---

@Samborski's method works fine in normal case but it does not work in python `subprocess.check_output` since the pts is not allocated. If you use `nvim`, you can use this more straightforward way:

```
HOME=_ nvim --headless -es file <<EOF
call writefile([&ft], "/dev/stdout")
EOF
```

Comment: Python files, bash files, etc. are all just text files intended to be opened with different interpreters. You could guess at the correct interpreter to use by analyzing the file and looking for certain structures and keywords, but it would be a guess at best.

Comment: Of course it should be determined by the content of the file. My question is how. `vim` has a lot of code to handle this. `file` can also do this but it output is not something directly usable by pygmentize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vim this way:

```
vim -c ':silent execute ":!echo " . &ft . " > /dev/stdout"' -c ':q!' the_file
```

It simply constructs command to run in the shell as a string concatenation.

Comment: This one works, but it causes screen flash. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I found that the flash is caused by my plugins in `.vim`. What how can I disable those plugins

Comment: you can create another `.vimrc` file and the use it instead of the default one by specifying `-u <vimrc>` flag

Comment: It is `.vim` not the `.vimrc`. Using that I will need to modify the `rtp` in the vimrc. I just found another better way, it is to use `HOME=_ vim -c ...` to fake a home dir so that vim will not be able to find my own settings. Do you mind to add this part to you answer? I will accept yours. Thank you

Comment: There is also `--noplugin` flag available

Comment: `--noplugin` will not load any plugin so that file detection will fail. I need to keep the standard plugins shipped with vim but exclude my personal ones in `.vim`

Comment: `vim -u NORC` (`:help -u`).

Comment: @Amadan, `-u NORC` only disables `.vimrc`, The plugins in `.vim/plugin` and other folders in it will still run

Comment: `.vim/plugin` is not a location Vim looks at. It is the package manager that you run from your `.vimrc`(Vundle, NeoBundle, Pathogen, VimPlug...) that makes Vim aware of `.vim/plugin`. No `.vimrc` = no custom plugins. However. you _do_ want Vim's default plugins to run because you want `filetype.vim`, the plugin responsible for detecting the file types.